# How to Create Styled Dataframe on Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe
[image: 1]
I would like to add some color styling to my dataframe.
I tried the following code:

```py
df2 = df.style.applymap(
    lambda x: f"color :{'red' if 'Not Ready' in str(x) else 'green' if 'Ready' in str(x) else 'black'}"
)
```

and I get new styled dataframe like this:

[image: 2]

But the dataframe that I wanted is like this:
[image: 3]

Can you help me solve this problem using pandas?

Comment: Why are the values here in title case `Not Ready`, while in the output/original they're upper case `NOT READY`?

Comment: I have already use upper case for NOT READY and READY but the result is still the same

Comment: Try concatenation after the style, not before. (your current method applies ONE style to a whole string, not different styles to different parts of a string)